# Javascript/ajax is passing all form textfield values to the php but not the last textfield value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my html with form and javascript/ajax function. All the textfield values are passed to the test.php. When I do so, if i enter the first three textfields then test.php will successfully display the form values. But on the other hand, if I fill all the four textfield and send then nothing will happen. Since, I am new in the programming, i could not figure this issue out. I would be thankful for the solution of this issue.

```
    #form.html

    <html>
    <SCRIPT language="javaScript">

    function sendData(){
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                else
                    {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXobject ('Mircosoft.XMLHTTP');
                    }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }

                var i=0;
                var arr = new Array();

                while ((document.getElementById(i).value)) {
                if ((document.getElementById(i).value)!=""){                
                    var activity = document.getElementById(i).value;            
                    arr[i] = activity;
                }           
                i++;
                }

                var params = 'activity='+JSON.stringify(arr);
                xmlhttp.open('POST','test.php', true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

                xmlhttp.send(params);
                document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Sending...";        
                }   

                </script>

    <form action="#" method="POST">
    <tr>Name1:<td> <input type="text" id="0"/> </td></tr><br>
    <tr>Name2:<td> <input type="text" id="1"/> </td></tr><br>
    <tr>Name3:<td> <input type="text" id="2"/> </td></tr><br>
    <tr>Name4:<td> <input type="text" id="3"/> </td></tr><br>
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendData()";/>
    </form>

     <div id="message">            
    </div>

    </html>
```

This is the test.php file where the form value will be displayed.

```
    #test.php
    <?php
    $activity = $_POST['activity'];
    $activity = json_decode($activity);

    if (is_array($activity)){
        foreach ($activity as $value){
            echo $value."<br>";
            }
        }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It's because your `while` loop is flawed, why aren't you using a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: `<script language="javascript">` is deprecated. Please use `<script type="text/javascript">`. Also could you place an `alert` to see if all your `activity` values are being received correct?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with

```
while ((document.getElementById(i).value)) {
```

It works just fine until `i === 4`, then `getElementById` returns `null`, and `null.value` is an error, so the whole thing errors out.

Using a while loop for this doesn't really seem like a good idea, but something like this should at least work

```
        while (document.getElementById(i)) {
            if ((document.getElementById(i).value) != "") {
                arr[i] = document.getElementById(i).value;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Getting the elements by class, tagname or something else other than numeric ID's seems better

```
        var arr = new Array();
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs'); // class

        for ( var i=0; i<elems.length; i++ ) {
            arr.push(elems[i].value)
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers and quick reply. Studying your above answer I came to figure out the one solution.

I have changed the code like this and it worked!!!. Once again thanks you!!!

    while (document.getElementById(i)!=null) {
    if ((document.getElementById(i).value)!=""){    
        var activity = document.getElementById(i).value;   
     arr[i] = activity;
     }   
     i++;
    }

Comment: null is falsy, so my answer is exactly the same, feel free to accept it.